# rsync -av --delete /sourceFolder/ /Mounted cifs format windows share folder/

Tags: samba, backup, rsync, shared-folders

I successfully mounted a Windows share folder by editing `/etc/fstab`. Now I'm trying to `rsync` Ubuntu folders to the mounted Windows share folder in Ubuntu system.

I'm using the command `rsync -av --delete /sourceFolder/ /Mounted cifs format windows share folder/`. Everything works fine without the option for the permissions.

The copied file permissions follow the uid, gid, dir_mode options in `/etc/fstab` file, not the rsync `-a` option.

Is there a workaround to preserve the file permissions when backing up? Or is my approach wrong fundamentally?

Comment: This is an important issue for me. Otherwise I have to spend a lot of money. Would anyone please give me a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the flag `-p` to preserve permissions.

Comment: While this answer may point to the correct usage, the lack of explanation and no useful detail makes this answer almost useless.